# Python: execute on last iteration of while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

My goal is to execute an operation on the last operation of while loop only. My while loop is nested in a for loop.

Currently I go for:

```
for i in range(10):
    indicator = False
    while(...):
       do something
       indicator = True  
    if indicator == True:
        do one operation
        indicator = False
    do something not in while loop
```

While it seems to work, it doesn't look elegant. Is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: That's generally how I would do it

Comment: you literally wrote your own answer in your own question :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using break in while loop, you can use `while ... else` expression.

https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-while-else/

Comment: I don't think this answers the question because the `else` clause will run whether or not the loop was entered.

Comment: @Jeff yes just checked it once again. it does not actually do what I intent do to